# Unresolved reference when building Kotlin source code

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jvm, smartcard

I'm trying to build project written in Kotlin that has classes with references to `javax.smartcardio` package. As build system Gradle is used. And when I try to build system just shows "Unresolved reference" message. `java.smartcardio` module is a part of JDK and I'm using as target JVM version 8 so I think there is no necessity in `module-info.java` files.

I googled a lot and have not found any solution for now. So would appreciate any advice.
Also I'm full time C# developer so Java, Kotlin is very new for me.

Link to source of project that I try to build:
`https://github.com/tangem/tangem-sdk-android`

Some screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

This are the gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${versions.kotlin}"
     implementation project(':tangem-sdk-core')
     implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9'
     implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:1.3.9"
     implementation "com.squareup.sqldelight:sqlite-driver:1.4.3" 
}
```

Comment: maybe you are using the wrong import for your smart card io, Try to delete the import and import the right one, Perhaps there is more than one kind of smart card  io

Comment: @providerZ,  
Tried to import in different other classes with same result. 
Also if I create `.java` class instead of `.kt` class so package smartcardio is visible without any problem

Comment: then check the SDKs versions make sure they have the same versions the Gradle and the kotlin

Comment: @providerZ, versions looks like everywhere pointed the same. JDK 11 and target JVM 8

Comment: Please add the gradle dependencies

Comment: Please edit your question to convert the image into text in the post, and use a [code block](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for any code you have. This will make it easier to answer your question because readers can search the text or copy the code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use javax.smartcardio package on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47049308/how-to-use-javax-smartcardio-package-on-android)

Comment: @dan1st
Will convert to code blocks.
As I assume this has nothing to do with Android. I think this is like multiplatform project. And module com.tangem.jvm is for desktop since module com.tangem.sdk.android does not depend on it.

Comment: @cutiko
This is dependencies for com.tangem.jvm module
`dependencies {  
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${versions.kotlin}"

    implementation project(':tangem-sdk-core')

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:1.3.9"
    implementation "com.squareup.sqldelight:sqlite-driver:1.4.3"
}`

Comment: Tangem documentation explicitly says to add the dependencies using gradle, why are you adding them as a local project?

https://developers.tangem.com/getting-started/android
https://developers.tangem.com/getting-started/jvm

Comment: @cutico I'm not adding anything. Just pulled sdk project from repository and trying to build. By  that link you posted they say about to add ready compiled sdk to user custom projects, but my intention is to learn source code of their sdk and compile it locally.